# Modeling web based decision tables

Tags: representation

I am trying to build a web based application that will help business to design/define non-technical business rules using a decision table concept. My decision table would look something like this,

[image: Sample Decision table]

I am also planning to add functionalities like 
1) Adding new Fact/Rule/Action
2) Removing Fact/Rule/Action.

I will be having more than 100 sheets grouped under various categories where each sheet can move the focus to another sheet in the same category or to a different category itself. Currently we are using Microsoft excel to represent this as shown in the snapshot.

Question: 
1. What is the best way to represent this?
2. Is/Are there any web widgets that I can use.

Comment: Anything wrong with flow charts? They've been around sometime.

Comment: Or checkout airline emergency checklists, they've been doing it for decades and they're the very definition of clarity, due to their nature.

Comment: When i try to put each rule (A, B, C...) into a conditional block of a flow chart i feel that the rules are separated from each other i.e. the relationship between each rule is visually taken away (the rules look more related when i see them next to each other in a matrix format than separated into a box). I haven't tried taking an example to do it. Let me try and post the outcome. Moreover the main reason for this project is to let business create / modify rules. so the main essence of this UI would be to show the rules as much related as possible to ease the visualization.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that a more visual approach like a flowchart is best.  Readability of the matrix is very low, and a lot of the density is unnecessary.

To address your concern about separating the rules, you could consider allowing users to define policy functions in one area, then place instances of those functions in the flowchart.  So the rule definitions would live in one place (reducing complexity), but the references would be show at the point of decision (improving readability).  On an infinite budget you could also have instances link to the function definition and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, right now we are going with the tabular representation for phase one to let BA/Business author rules using the current format (Tabular). This will let the project manage the rules much better than an excel sheet. Based on this for my question 2 is there any web widget close enough to represent a matrix that i can further customize. Phase two would be to use this tabular info to generate a flowchart/rule flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I find Decision Tables an excellent way to define requirements and test cases.

There are two differences I use from yours:  I number Actions starting at 1 again, and I left-justify the text.

You might also want to consider showing a dash (-) for empty cells so the user knows it is not applicable rather than missing information.

Option 1

Portray your tables exactly like you have them in a table or a grid, and add hyperlinks or buttons.

With this option, I'm assuming you expect users to be on a tablet or larger.

Tables and grids are very common web components that you can find practically anywhere.  You don't mention your programming language/environment.
Something like one of these come to mind:

[image]

Option 2

Instead of displaying everything in one decision table, capture the information in a database using standard CRUD UI, and let the user answer questions at run-time that determines and displays the actions.
This code is not my own, but came from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decision_tables#JavaScript
And there is a demo to see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/rGP6C/1/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form id="form"></form>
    <br/>Possible solutions:
    <ul id="ul"></ul>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var questions = [
        { bools:[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], text:"Printer does not print" },
        { bools:[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0], text:"A red light is flashing" },
        { bools:[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0], text:"Printer is unrecognized" },
    ];
    var answers = [
        { bools:[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], text:"Check the power cable" },
        { bools:[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], text:"Check the printer-computer cable" },
        { bools:[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0], text:"Ensure printer software is installed" },
        { bools:[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0], text:"Check/replace ink" },
        { bools:[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0], text:"Check for paper jam" },
    ]

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Init form with questions. "Value" is a descending power of 2.
        var value = questions[0].bools.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            value /= 2;
            var el = '<br /><input type="checkbox" value="' + value + '">' + questions[i].text;
            $("#form").append(el);
        }

        // Respond to a checkbox action.
        $('input:checkbox').change(function() {

            // Figure out which combination of checkboxes the user selected.
            var sum = 0;
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                sum += Number(this.value);
            });

            // Translate sum into an index (column #) into bools.
            var index = questions[0].bools.length - sum - 1;

            // Clear the answers.
            $('#ul').html('');

            // Add appropriate answers.
            for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
                if (answers[i].bools[index]) {
                    $('#ul').append('<li>' + answers[i].text + '</li>')
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Option 3

[Use a flexrule web component](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/decision-table-web-component/)

Option 4

Use a web-based business rules engine like SAP, CodeEffects, Pega, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. we are proceeding something like your Option 1 where Business/BA's would develop their requirements tro a web application that will record all the info and store into a DB. Phase two will be to interact with Jboss drools BRMS (our current rules engine) to automatically make changes where ever possible (This is to replace the Drools KIE workbench which according to us is not business user (non technical) friendly).